# Best trader from an European perspective

Tags: trading, europe

I would like to buy some bitcoins (and potentially litecoins). I live in Europe, what is the best way to get and trade them from Europe? I would like to avoid all unnecessary fees, as much as possible.

Thanks.

I've also heard that MtGox has some problems and withdraw the money from there is quite annoying in this period.

Comment: People who vote to close: It's great that you do it but it's even better if someone adds a comment explaining to the (new) user why it is a bad question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option is [Bitstamp.net](https://www.bitstamp.net) which is currently the exchange with the biggest trade volume world wide, operating out of UK. SEPA deposits valued in Euro are free and so is the withdrawal of Bitcoin. Deposits valued in USD and GBP have a minimal fee of 15$/15£ respectively.
They charge up to 0.5% commission on trades, less if you trade more.

I can't guarantee this is actually the best option, but they have a simple process in place and act as escrow. At least for small volumes of bitcoin the fees are better than [Bitcoin.de](https://www.bitcoin.de), where they charge 1% commission and MtGox (up to 0.6%).

You can find a list of more exchange services on [http://bitcoin.it](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:Exchanges).
However, at least some entries seem to be horribly outdated (e.g. Bitcoin24 was last updated in April 2013, yet there were some developments concerning their availability since then).