# Bitcoin Sellers who Request Photo ID, is this safe?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I wanted to comment on this but couldn't due to low rep:

[What's the safest way to buy bitcoins in the UK?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13264/whats-the-safest-way-to-buy-bitcoins-in-the-uk)

Looks like quickbitcoin.co.uk is a good place to buy bitcoins, however; I'm not comfortable sending my driving licence or other ID.

Why do companies/sellers of crypto currency want photo ID of customers?  Is it safe?

Answer (score 1):

Cryptocurrency companies generally require photo identification to protect the company. The legal concern of exchange of cryptocurrency is money laundering, and by requiring identity verification, you know who you're receiving currency from or giving it to. Of course, companies will also need to have procedures in place to detect identity fraud. Some exchanges will require you to provide a picture of yourself holding your photo identification.

As for whether it is safe or not, it really depends on how trustworthy people believe the company is.